# How to track html attribute change

Tags: html, angular, angular8

I'm working with angular 8.
I have a list of details tags display through `*ngFor`:

```
<ul class="chronology">
  <li *ngFor="let event of events; index as i" class="chronology" >
    <details class="panel">
      <summary>
        <div>
          <span class="appName">{{event.application.name}}</span>
        </div>
      </summary>
      <div class="description"><p class="clear">{{event.description}}</p> 
     </div>
    </details>
  </li>
</ul>
```

When I click on the details pane, it opens the div "description" as expected and adds an attribute open to details tag, so it actually looks like this

```
<details class="panel" open>
```

**My problem :**

I would like to keep track of the details state and get to know in my angular code if I have a details opened or not.

How can I bind an angular property to those attribute `open`?

Answer (score 2):

Create an array `isOpened:boolean = []` which will be of same size as your `events` array.
Then whenever you click on `details` panel bind it to a function which will store the boolean value to let you know which `descriptions` are open. Below is just a gist of what you can do and you can tweak it to toggle the state of `descriptions`

> .html file code

```
<details class="panel" (click)="clickHandler(i)">
```

> .ts file code

```
clickHandler(index:number){
   isOpened[index]=true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the Himanshu's Answer: [StackBlitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-futhat)

Maintain an array on the typescript side containing boolean values(default *false*) for every details tag:

```
  eventArr = Array<boolean>(this.events.length).fill(false);
```

Pass the index from the HTML tag:

```
<details  class="panel" (click)='onClick(i)'>
```

Toggle values in the boolean array(eventArr) on click:

```
onClick(index): void {
 this.eventArr[index]  = !this.eventArr[index];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete working example you can find-out here in this [Stack Blitz Link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jkbtpz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

I want to give you robust solution using `Observable` and `DRY code structure`. You dont need to use seperate state-management for just knowing which details is open or close.

First, you have to define your `template-reference` variable for each `details tag`. Then in component using `@ViewChild()` you can access each details `ElementRef` using `QueryList<>` array.

This is your template.html...

```
<ul class="alert alert-primary ">
    <li *ngFor="let event of events; index as i; trackBy: trackElement" class="chronology" >
       <details  class="alert alert-danger" #detailsElements (click)="open(i)">
         <summary>
            <span> Is Open :  {{event?.isOpen}} </span>
            <div>
              <span class="appName">{{event.application.name}}</span>
            </div>
         </summary>
          <div class="description"><p class="clear">{{event.description}}</p></div>
       </details>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In, Above code `#detailsElements` is our teplate reference variable. and in each `details` click event we call `open(i)` method. we are also using `trackBy` in `*ngFor` for performance improvement, to load only changed object to DOM rather than re-creating whole DOM. In you component.ts you can have reference using `@ViewChildren()`...

```
 @ViewChildren('detailsElements') attendeeInputs: QueryList<ElementRef>;
```

and your events object looks like this...

```
events = [
  {
    application:{
      name:'first'
    },
    description: 'description'
  },
  {
    application:{
      name:'Second'
    },
    description: ' Seconnd description'
  }
];
```

In your open() method is...

```
open(i){
  let toggle;
  const detailsElement = this.attendeeInputs.filter((element,index)=> index === i)
  detailsElement.forEach((element,j) => {
    toggle = !element.nativeElement.open;
    this.events[i]['isOpen'] = toggle; 
  })
  this.isOpenState$  = of(  this.events.filter ( keys => keys['isOpen'] ) ) 
}
```

In, Open method we are getting index i from *ngFor and then we are filtering `detailsElements` to get reference for only which is clicked. we can get now open state using `element.nativeElement.open` and assign it to toggle variable.

Then, we are creating new property called `isOpen` in existing object of `this.events` and thus then we are giving this newly creating object to `of()` method of RXJS to creating observable. and thus whenever, any selection of `details` changes according to them our observable value changes and thus we are in sync with template and component.ts